# gdal.VectorTranslateOptions options-Parameter

Tags: python, gdal, openstreetmap

I want to convert all lines from a .osm-File to a geojson with the gdal Python API.
My Code so far:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr

gdal.UseExceptions()

srcds = gdal.OpenEx("infile.osm")
gdaloptions = gdal.VectorTranslateOptions(format="GEOJSON", layers = ["lines"])

ds = gdal.VectorTranslate("outfile.geojson", srcds, options=gdaloptions)
```

This returns a lot of erros like:
`ERROR 1: Non increasing node id. Use OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO`

According to the [Documenation of VectorTranslateOptions()](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.VectorTranslateOptions) I changed gdaloptions to:

```
gdaloptions = gdal.VectorTranslateOptions(options=['OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO'],
                                          format="GEOJSON",
                                          layers = ["lines"])
```

But this returns an other error: `Couldn't fetch requested layer OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO!`

How do I set this ["Open Options" of the osm-Format](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html#open-options) within the `VectorTranslateOptions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also possible to set OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING as a config option https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html#internal-working-and-performance-tweaking

Usage:

`gdal.SetConfigOption("USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING", "NO")`

With open options this should work:

```
ds = gdal.OpenEx(
        "file.osm",
        open_options=["OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO"],
```

Comment: `gdal.SetConfigOption("OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING", "NO")` works great!
But `ds = gdal.OpenEx("file.osm",open_options=["OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO"])` doesn't -> `Warning 6: driver OSM does not support open option OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING`

Comment: Closer look at the documentation https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html#open-options reveals that the name of the open option is shortened to `USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING`. I will edit the answer.